# For loop stopping execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

hoping this is a simple question.

I have a If statement that runs a for loop inside of it:

```
if(createRequest.data.status == "COMPLETE"){
                
                for(let f = 0; f <= createRequest.data.results.length; f++){
                    testHubInfo.push(createRequest.data.results[f].id)
                    associationArray.push({
                        "from": {
                            "id": `${createRequest.data.results[f].id}`
                        },
                        "to": {
                            "id": `${eventID}`
                        }
                    })
                }

                testHubInfo.push("Ugh")
                testHubInfo.push(associationArray)
            }
```

the problem with this, is that this runs, it gets to the for loop and adds to testHubInfo & associationArray arrays , but then after that it just ends execution of that function and none of the following things get ran, such as the "Ugh". It even refuses to run the code *after* the If statement:

```
            testHubInfo.push("Got here to assoc?")
            await batchCreateAssociations(associationArray, eventID)

            context.log("SUCCESS")
            context.log("==============")
            return true;
```

so hoping someone can help assist! Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: `<= length` seems like an off-by-one error. This is where [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can help. It really can't miss.

Comment: That's what I thought too and I apologize for not including this up above - it actually does run that testHubInfo,push above associationArray.push

Comment: You can walk off the end of an array in JavaScript, but that should lead to the `.id` part being invalid. Why not use `map()` here? `testHubInfo = createRequest.data.results.map(r => r.id)` for example.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that your bash-style template string with nothing but a singular value in it is odd. Is that just to "stringify" those numbers? [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is often more clear, but that's just my opinion. What you're doing here seems kind of pointless as JavaScript treats strings and numbers pretty loosely internally.

Comment: Yeah, outside API that requires a odd formatting. I'll try the map thing though, that's a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: I feel that! Still, `{ "id": ... }` and `{ id: ... }` are literally the same thing in JavaScript since keys are always stringified. Can help keep your code more minimal.